# Destination folder issue in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

My installer runs 2 exe files and I wish to give the user the abbiltey to choose the destination folder for the first exe program, I don't wrap the exe files under [Files] section instead I download them
the problme is that the installer dosent install the main exe file in the destination I chose in the select dir page, how come? and how can I solve this
here is the code-

```
[Setup]
AppName={#ReadIni(SourcePath + "Bundletemplate.ini", "setupValues", "AppName", "")}
AppVersion={#ReadIni(SourcePath + "Bundletemplate.ini", "setupValues", "AppVersion", "")}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#ReadIni(SourcePath + "Bundletemplate.ini", "setupValues", "AppURL", "")}
AppSupportURL={#ReadIni(SourcePath + "Bundletemplate.ini", "setupValues", "AppURL", "")}
AppUpdatesURL={#ReadIni(SourcePath + "Bundletemplate.ini", "setupValues", "AppURL", "")}
AppCopyright={#ReadIni(SourcePath + "Bundletemplate.ini", "setupValues", "CopyRight", "")}
DefaultDirName={pf}\AppName
DefaultGroupName=AppName
OutputDir=Setup_File
OutputBaseFilename={#ReadIni(SourcePath + "Bundletemplate.ini", "setupValues", "BundleOutputName", "")}
SetupIconFile=..\Assets\{#ReadIni(SourcePath + "Bundletemplate.ini", "setupValues", "iconfile", "")}
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
DisableReadyMemo=True
DisableReadyPage=True
DisableDirPage=No
DisableWelcomePage=True
DisableFinishedPage=True
Uninstallable=no

#include <idp.iss>
[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"


[Files]
Source: "Bundletemplate.ini"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: ignoreversion

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\MOInstaller.exe"; Description: ""; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: waituntilterminated; BeforeInstall: MOBeforeInstall; AfterInstall: MOafterInstall; Parameters:"{#ReadIni(SourcePath + "Bundletemplate.ini", "setupValues", "Appcommand", "")} {code:Switches}"
Filename: "{tmp}\SOInstaller.exe"; Description: ""; Check: DontInstallSP; Flags: nowait ; BeforeInstall: SOBeforeInstall; AfterInstall: SOafterInstall;  Parameters:"{#ReadIni(SourcePath + "Bundletemplate.ini", "setupValues", "OfferAppcommand", "")} -carrier_id={code:CTID} -installation_session_id={code:SessionID}"
```

Comment: Is any of the *external* installers built with Inno Setup ? If so, you can pass it the expanded `{app}` constant to the `/DIR` command line parameter to *prefill* the destination directory. The rest I don't understand, since a lot of information is hidden in some INI files and missing code functions.

Comment: the external installers are not built with Inno Setup, I thought the "WorkingDir: "{app}";" I inserted for the first installer will do the trick, but nothing!

Comment: Try to take it from our perspective. It's difficult to tell what you are asking at this time. If you are asking about how to instruct those installers to use the `{app}` directory, then we must know at least what they are built in because we cannot guess command line parameters somehow. And I'm not that much surprised that working directory was ignored by that installer. Installers usually use default directories located somewhere in program files folders. Inno Setup e.g. uses `DefaultDirName` directive for that, and the only way to pre-define it from outside is through the command line.

Comment: I understand, what you're saying is Inno installer can't tell the external installer where to install itself unless getting information from the ext installer itself, right?

Comment: Inno Setup is able to tell the *foreign* installer where to install e.g. by comamnd line parameters if that *foreign* installer supports it. For example Inno Setup uses the `/DIR` command line parameter, MSI `INSTALLDIR` etc. To answer you, we must know what type of installer it is.

Comment: great prob solved I found the external CMD- "/installdir=" and I gave it the "{app}" value, it works